# Unknow error about conversion

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs

I've got this angularJs call to a asmx WebMethod, but I receive an error about conversion. Here the code

**AngulaJs call:**

```
$scope.delete = function (idNews) {
    var url = '/data_db.asmx/SetDeleteNews';
    var obj = idNews
    $http.post(url,obj)
    .success(
        function (response) {
            if (response.Error) {
                console.log('Impossibile to remove.' + response.Message);
            }
        })
    .error(
        function (response) {
            console.log('Error:' + response.ExceptionType);
            console.log(response.Message);
            console.log(response.StackTrace);
        });
}
```

**The WebMethod, in C#:**

```
public bool SetDeleteNews(int i)
{
    News n = new News
    {
        id = i,
        title = string.Empty,
        arg = string.Empty,
        isDeleted = true,
    };

    bool result = BONewsLINQ.DeleteNews(n);
    return result;
}
```

**And the BO:**

```
public static bool DeleteNews(News delete)
{
    using (Entity news = new Entity ())
    {
        try
        {
            News remove = news.News.Where(n => n.id == delete.id).FirstOrDefault();
            news.News.Remove(remove);
            news.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        } catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**The error is:**

```
Error:System.InvalidOperationException
Cannot convert object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)


at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)
```

I'm only pass an int value (in var obj), but return this error. Why? Thanks

Comment: It should be `$http.post(url, {id: idNews})`

Comment: Error: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'i'.

Comment: you may want to try ..... var obj = JSON.stringify({ "i": idNews})

Comment: Ok, works with `$http.post(url, {id: idNews})`, just place i instead id. Thanks!